# How to implement client authentication in netcoreserver SSL chat example

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, networking

I'm trying to implement client authentication using the netcoreserver library and I have no clue of where to start. Specifically I would like to add client authentication to the example code provided with the library, i.e. SslChatServer and SslChatClient. Also I would like to know when the authentication has failed but it is unclear where to check this. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to supply the client certificate in the server code but this crashs the program. I don't know what to try.

Comment: If by _"netcoreserver"_ you are referring to [this](https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer) GitHub project, with 120 issues and an unusual [history](https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer/graphs/code-frequency), I'm not sure if I would want to use it.  Looking at the [code](https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer/blob/6d0fef1bd2cccfe9fdfc238fcfd88a5048316d7b/source/NetCoreServer/SslServer.cs#L15) just now it's not even `await`ing async operations!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.